# PHP/Javascript: Where to specify components of a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, angularjs

I have recently been trying to alter someone else's code however am a complete beginner when it comes to PHP/Javascript. I want to add an extra option to a drop down menu that specifies the Read/Write nature of an object. Currently the only options are 'R' and 'W' however I would like to add an R/W option for Read/Write. To the best of my knowledge I believe the drop down list itself is instantiated here however please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Read/Write:</label>
                <div  class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in readWrite" ng-model="singleRegister.RW" ng-change="modbusChange(modbusDetailsEdit)"> </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Where should I be looking in the code for the items in the list? I found this in a javascript file that seemed like what i was looking for:

```
$scope.readWrite=['R','W'];
```

However when i altered it to look as below nothing changed in the code

```
$scope.readWrite=['R','W','R/W'];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This is the list in question FWIW...

[image]

Comment: The element you are showing is just a normal text input, it doesn't seem to  be using `$scope.readWrite` in any way

Comment: @li0n_za who knows what framework he might be using ... looks like angular ... probably should add that tag.

Comment: @Jakumi, yes, that is definitely angularJS

Comment: Apologies appears I copied the wrong section, does this look more like what it should be?

Comment: @Mst137, yes, it would seem that you are on the correct course.  I would suggest checking if `$scope.readWrite` and your html are running in the same scope

Comment: @li0n_za, I would assume they were as the list works perfectly fine with the two original options, and even when a third is added it works fine, just wont display the third :(

Comment: @li0n_za Although now, if I also remove all options from $scope.readWrite it also still displays the same two options as before...

Comment: @Mst137, that means that the `$scope.readWrite` you are editing is not the one accessed in your html

Comment: @li0n_za but it is not declared/used anywhere else? the html file is seperate to the controller, how do I say in the html file to link to the scope in the controller?

Comment: @Mst137, I cannot really help with the content you provided, use `{{<pre>{{$scope|json}}</pre>}}` in your html to see which scope you are dealing with